# Drop-Down Menu of Current Child Pages

Tags: child-pages, get-children

I would like to display the child pages of the current page in a select menu, I.E. =>

```
<select><option>This is a child page</option><option>This is another child page</option></select>
```

Of course, the option markup would be the dynamic function; markup that says basically that we want to display the child pages of the current page wrapped in an option field for each one.

The result should be a drop-down menu that someone could select the child pages title and submit it with the form. The reason being, the child pages are tours and all I need is the title to be passed to a select field so we know that' the tour they're interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be approached by using [`wp_dropdown_pages()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_pages) with the `child_of` parameter.

```
global $post;
$args = array(
    'child_of'         => $post->ID
);
wp_dropdown_pages( $args );
```

The variable name will be `$_GET['post_id']` or `$_POST['post_id']`, depending on your form settings, you can change the name by altering the `name` parameter. The value of the variable is the `ID` of the chosen page. Use [`get_the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title) to get it from the id in your $_GET/$_POST variable.